# Setting the height of all ListView itemsand having them scroll together

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have three ListViews, nameList, positionList, and numberList, which get their contents from their respective arrays. I need to have their items/cells all have the same height, and all ListViews have to scroll together, both of which seem like easy things to do, but there is no apparent option...? How would I go about this?

Comment: Use weights to accomplish part 1, can you explain part 2 more. Do you mean if you sroll list a, list b and c sroll too, or do you mean all of them are scrollable?

Comment: Do you want to put all three ListView in sequence, i.e. after nameList data of positionList gets started?